# mysql query takes a lot of time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

This query in rails does not come to an end. Why?
Query is:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(f.name, ' ', f.parent_names) AS FullName,
       stts.name AS 'Status',
       u.name AS Unit,
       city.name AS City,
       hus.mobile1 AS HusbandPhone,
       wife.mobile1 AS WifePhone,
       f.phone AS HomePhone,
       f.contact_initiation_date AS InitDate,
       fh.created_at AS StatusChangeDate,
       cmt.created_at AS CommentDate,
       cmt.comment AS LastComment,
       f.reconnection_date AS ReconnectionDate,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.name, ' ')
   FROM taggings tgs
   JOIN tags t ON tgs.tag_id = t.id
   WHERE tgs.taggable_type = 'family'
     AND tgs.taggable_id = f.id) AS HandlingStatus
FROM families f
JOIN categories stts ON f.family_status_cat_id = stts.id
JOIN units u ON f.unit_id = u.id
JOIN categories city ON f.main_city_cat_id = city.id
LEFT JOIN contacts hus ON f.husband_id = hus.id
LEFT JOIN contacts wife ON f.wife_id = wife.id
LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
AND cmt.created_at =
  (SELECT MAX(created_at)
   FROM comments
   WHERE commentable_id = f.id)
LEFT JOIN family_histories fh ON f.id = fh.family_id
AND fh.created_at =
  (SELECT MAX(created_at)
   FROM family_histories
   WHERE family_id = f.id
     AND family_history_cat_id = 1422)
AND fh.family_history_cat_id = 1422
WHERE 1=0
  OR (f.family_status_cat_id = 1422
      AND (  (SELECT MAX(_fh.created_at)
              FROM family_histories _fh
              WHERE _fh.family_history_cat_id = 1422
                AND _fh.family_id = f.id
                AND _fh.new_val LIKE '%1422%') BETWEEN '2010-03-10' AND '2011-03-02'))
```

Am I missing something? Synatx is correct, so what is the problem?

Comment: what does your `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Are the tables indexed? How many records each table? We can't answer just based on a pasted query (not even formatted) why the performance is not as good as you would expect.

Comment: do your individual queries run successfully? I would trim this down to the bare minimum and work from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have to much subqueries. It has to take a lot of time.

My recommendation would be to store some of the information you get by subqueries in the main table.

In alternative you can always try to make a store procedure to speed up the process.

Best regards